# При адаптивной верстке сьезжают блоки

Tags: адаптивная-верстка

Друзья, занимаюсь не так давно, решил с нуля сделать сайт своими ручками, чтобы прочувствовать все на своей "шкуре" и тут возник ступор, точнее их два:

1) Не работает форма отправки в телеграмм, хотя все сделал по инструкции.
Появляется ошибка, мол слетела кодировка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Если смотреть на вторую секцию, когда начинаешь сжимать экран все элементы налазят друг на друга.

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Профиль данного проекта на гите: https://github.com/NickolayKapitanov/NickolayKapitanov.github.io-elena-browlash.

Ссылка на gh-pages: https://nickolaykapitanov.github.io/NickolayKapitanov.github.io-elena-browlash/

Буду рад услышать так же, любые адекватные замечания.

Comment: 1) не используйте позиционирование блоков используйте padding или margin для контролирования отступов
2) когда избавитесь от позиционирования всех блоков у нас все получиться

Comment: @Yamich спасибо большое все поправил :), все работает урааа
Насчет формы вы случаем не в курсе, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте убрать фигурные скобки в вашем запросе `https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}`

Comment: @Yamich попробовал, не получилось. Как была ошибка, так и осталась (я ее скрин добавил в вопрос). Мне кстати в групповой чат с ботом, кто-то прислал {test}

Comment: это был я просто в просто проверил саму строку